# scala: Initialization of array of immutable objects

Tags: scala

```
    class x(x:int){val y=x}

    class z {
        val grid= Array.ofDim(8,8)
    }
```

Is that object already initialized?
 when i try to initialize in loop like

```
    for(i<-0 until 8;j<-0 until 8) grid(i)(j)=new x(someValue)
```

i am getting error: Null pointer exception

Comment: Btw, `class Foo(x: Int) {val y=x }` and `class Foo(val y: Int)` are essentially the same

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.fill](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array$@fill[T](n1:Int,n2:Int,n3:Int,n4:Int,n5:Int)(elem:=%3ET)(implicitevidence$13:scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]):Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[T]]]]]) like this `val grid = Array.fill(8, 8) { new X(1) }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.fill`:

```
Array.fill(8, 8)(myValue)
```

Or you can use `toArray` with a nested `for` comprehension:

```
{  
  for { 
    i <- 0 until 8 
  } yield { for { 
    j <- 0 until 8 
  } yield myValue 
}.toArray }.toArray
```

Similarly, you can use `toArray` with `map`:

```
(0 until 8).map { _ => (0 until 8).map { _ => myValue }.toArray }.toArray
```

You could also use some combination of these approaches:

```
Array.fill(8){ { for(_ <- (0 until 8)) yield myValue }.toArray }
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are by definition mutable in Scala. They are essentially Java arrays enhanced with a lot of Scala's cool Collection APIs.

The main issue with what you have is the missing type parameterization of the Array. By specifying that the Array is of type `[X]` then the following code works great for me:

```
class X(x:Int){val y=x}

class Z {
   val grid= Array.ofDim[X](8,8)
   for(i<-0 until 8;j<-0 until 8) grid(i)(j)=new X(2)
}
```

Comment: i specified type parameter, still same problem,
I have initial some parts of array with one value and remaining parts with other value.
It is working when using var, but i don't want to use var

Comment: Can you add the exact code you have or something closer to how you populate the array? Var or Val should not make much difference in this setting.

Comment: i have a 2d array of objects. i have to initialize some parts of array by randomization first, then remaining parts depending on those earlier initialized parts.   
        for(i<-0 until 8){

Comment: the way i am initializing object in loop, is it correct or not? because i am not able to. just like loop, i first have to initialize 4 objects randomly. In am simple loop counting to 4 randomly generating x and y and passing it as grid(x)(y)=new Object(params). i also have to check that, if that object is already initialized or not. if it is already initialized then generate new x and y and generate a new object